# Dynamically add object to object

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects

I have `let prodObject = {schema: {}};`
And I have ul lists

```
        <ul class="product-lists">
            <li>CD Covers</li>
            <li>DVD Covers</li>
            <li>Cards</li>
            <li>Posters</li>
            <li>Cups</li>
        </ul>
```

I want to add object for each item in list in prodObject.schema object. 
I want to final object look like this.

````
                schema: {
                    cdCovers: { 
                        type: 'string',
                        title: 'CD Covers',
                    },
                    dvdCovers: { 
                        type: 'string',
                        title: 'DVD Covers',
                    },
                    cards: { 
                        type: 'string',
                        title: 'Cards',
                    }, 
                    posters: { 
                        type: 'string',
                        title: 'Posters',
                    },
                    cups: { 
                        type: 'string',
                        title: 'Cups',
                    },  
                }
            };```
````

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts to this. Selecting all the elements with [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), and then converting the titles to camelCase for the object keys with [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), [toLowerCase](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase), and [toUpperCase](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase):

```js
const prodObject = {schema:{}};

Array.from( document.querySelectorAll( '.product-lists li' ), el => el.innerText ).forEach( title => {
  const camelCaseTitle = title.replace( /^\w*/, x => x.toLowerCase( ) ).replace( /\s+(\w)(\w*)/, (_,f,r) => f.toUpperCase() + r.toLowerCase( ) );
  prodObject.schema[ camelCaseTitle ] = { type: 'string', title };
} );

console.log( prodObject );
```

```css
.product-lists {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="product-lists">
    <li>CD Covers</li>
    <li>DVD Covers</li>
    <li>Cards</li>
    <li>Posters</li>
    <li>Cups</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var prodObject = {schema: {}};
var productList = document.getElementsByClassName('product-lists')[0].children;

for (var i = 0; i < productList.length; i++) {
  var product = productList[i];
  var text = product.innerText;
  var key = text.split(' ').map(function(el) {
    return capitalizeFirstLetter(el);
  }).join('');
  key = key.charAt(0).toLowerCase() + key.slice(1);
  prodObject.schema[key] = {
    type: 'string',
    title: text
  };
}

console.log(prodObject);

function capitalizeFirstLetter(string) {
    return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1).toLowerCase();
}
```

```html
<ul class="product-lists">
            <li>CD Covers</li>
            <li>DVD Covers</li>
            <li>Cards</li>
            <li>Posters</li>
            <li>Cups</li>
</ul>
```